# Drag & Drop in jQuery with multiple <ul> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am able to drag & drop with "jQuery UI Sortable connectwith":
Like in below example. http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-ui/sortable-connectwith.html
It was working fine, but now I need to drag & drop with multiple UI. that is not working properly.
Example:

```
<ul><li> Item1 (with multiple image in carousel style) </li><ul>
<ul><li> Item2 (with multiple image in carousel style) </li><ul>
<ul><li> Item3 (with multiple image in carousel style) </li><ul>
<ul><li> Item4 (with multiple image in carousel style) </li><ul>
```

Can you some one help me in that? How can do that?

Comment: Show your js code and make a jsfiddle for this

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML needs to be proper. Check out the below demo

```
$("ul").sortable({
                connectWith: "ul",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                }
        });
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/uy10jxup/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for providing link. I am doing this but here I have one problem that when I drag the any item to up/down, It will be merge into another <ul>.
For e.g.: I am dragging "Item3" and dropped at top. So now Item1 and item3 are single <ul> element. At last for all dragging item, will be in single <ul> element. But I want to separate for all four items for sepearte <ul>.

Comment: This is because like I mentioned before you need to apply an id for each ul and then call this method. In the answer from @Yo Yo, he is getting the element with the tag. This function then gets all tags and calls the bind func for the first one and then can't decide which one is the correct ine. So again: just apply some ids to your ul tags and init them. Then you shell be good to go.

Comment: @PrSI : checkout my updated demo https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/uy10jxup/1/

Comment: @YoYo: Thanks for providing another example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are your `ui` - Tags. They are not available in Html. If you want to use this element you need to surround your `li` Tags with a `ul` Tag and remove all those invalid `ui` Tags.

Like in the example that is provided [here](http://www.pureexample.com/ExampleTesterII-81.html) you need to give each of the selectable lists an id and initialize the slider for them.

Comment: Thanks for correct me, I just edited. By mistake I written ui instead of ul. At actual code at my side its ul it self. But still not working.

Comment: Edited my answer. If you could provide your js Code i could give you further information.

Comment: For example @yo yo given example in his answer. I want same but UL element should be separated for each item when drag & drop from up/down.